# Can't create a mysql table: foreign key constraint issue

Tags: mysql, sql, database, constraints, magento2

I deleted a sql table (without key constraint check) and now i can't regenerate from sql query or import again.

creation query:

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

CREATE TABLE `customer_entity` (
  `entity_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL COMMENT 'Entity Id',
  `website_id` smallint(5) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Website Id',
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Email',
  `group_id` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Group Id',
  `increment_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Increment Id',
  `store_id` smallint(5) UNSIGNED DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Store Id',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Created At',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Updated At',
  `is_active` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Is Active',
  `disable_auto_group_change` smallint(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Disable automatic group change based on VAT ID',
  `created_in` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Created From',
  `prefix` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Prefix',
  `firstname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'First Name',
  `middlename` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Middle Name/Initial',
  `lastname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Last Name',
  `suffix` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Suffix',
  `dob` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Date of Birth',
  `password_hash` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Password_hash',
  `rp_token` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Reset password token',
  `rp_token_created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Reset password token creation time',
  `default_billing` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Default Billing Address',
  `default_shipping` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Default Shipping Address',
  `taxvat` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Tax/VAT Number',
  `confirmation` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Is Confirmed',
  `gender` smallint(5) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Gender',
  `failures_num` smallint(6) DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Failure Number',
  `first_failure` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'First Failure',
  `lock_expires` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Lock Expiration Date'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Customer Entity';

ALTER TABLE `customer_entity`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `CUSTOMER_ENTITY_EMAIL_WEBSITE_ID` (`email`,`website_id`),
  ADD KEY `CUSTOMER_ENTITY_STORE_ID` (`store_id`),
  ADD KEY `CUSTOMER_ENTITY_WEBSITE_ID` (`website_id`),
  ADD KEY `CUSTOMER_ENTITY_FIRSTNAME` (`firstname`),
  ADD KEY `CUSTOMER_ENTITY_LASTNAME` (`lastname`);


ALTER TABLE `customer_entity`
  MODIFY `entity_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Entity Id';


ALTER TABLE `customer_entity`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `CUSTOMER_ENTITY_STORE_ID_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `store` (`store_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `CUSTOMER_ENTITY_WEBSITE_ID_STORE_WEBSITE_WEBSITE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`website_id`) REFERENCES `store_website` (`website_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Error catched:

#1215 - Unable to add the referential integrity constraint (external key constraint)

I also tried to use `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;` but I did not succeed.
I tried to import the sql table again but without success.
In the creation query there are no key foreign constraints, so I can't figure out why query generates error.

The table is called "customer_entity.sql" on Magento 2 database.

Comment: Check `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS`, it will include more details about the most recent foreign key error. Like which table, the specific constraint that didn't work, etc.

Comment: That looks suspicious that the table has no `PRIMARY KEY` and no indexes at all. Is that really a Magento table? That's unusual and probably a matter of concern.

Comment: this is a query made from mysql  ( sql table export ).
i deleted all the key constraint definitions  to check if can solve the problem in this way. I don't know why no primary key, maybe i delete also the primary key definition.

Comment: Did you also delete some `FOREIGN KEY` definitions? Please understand it's really hard to help you when you are presenting code that is substantially different from the code exhibiting the error.

Comment: I edit with the full query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.

I changed my creation query, i renamed the table from "customer_entity" to "customer_entity2".

```
CREATE TABLE `customer_entity2` (
/* ..etc */

ALTER TABLE `customer_entity2`
/* ..etc */
```

So when i run the creation query mysql not checks all the key constraints.
Then i rename the table into "customer_entity" and the trick is done.

Is a too easy solution but i done it one minute ago and it works fine.
Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

Is the foreign key constraint on the other table?  If so, you might try removing it, creating this table, and then adding the constraint back in.

Comment: maybe there are some key constraint on other tables, but the error don't notify which tables. In Magento lot of tables are linked with foreign key, so i prefer a solution where i can load only the table.